# What is the difference between GCP's Cloud SQL Database and Cloud SQL Instance Database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to setup some monitoring of lock times in my Posgres Database on GCP. The metric I'm trying to use is `database/postgresql/insights/perquery/lock_time`[1](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-cloudsql).

What has confused me about this is that GCP Monitoring has said that this is available for Cloud SQL Instance Database and not Cloud SQL Database.

What is the difference and how would you monitor this in your own databases?

Answer (score 0):

A "*Cloud SQL instance*" can have many "*databases*". [This](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-databases#create) article on creating a database inside the instance may help to put this concept into perspective.

Your query lock time from Cloud metrics is worded in a way which implies that it can return results of a particular database name inside the instance itself. I suspect this since it says "Accumulated lock wait time per user per database" as a description.